# Regular expression to extract xgettext function names and params from cli args

Tags: javascript, regex, xgettext

I'm working on a CLI app, which allows the user to specify an argument with function names along with arguments. It's actually using the same syntax as `xgettext`, such as:

`--keywords=__,dgettext:2,dcgettext:2,ngettext:1,2,dpgettext2:2c,3`

I need to figure out a regex that would break this down into an array like this:

```
['__', 'dgettext:2', 'dcgettext:2', 'ngettext:1,2', 'dpgettext2:2c,3'];
```

How can I do it (in Javascript, for example)?

Here's what I have so far:

```
(((?!([0-9\s,])).|^)[a-zA-Z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*[:]*([0-9]*[a-z]*,*)*)
```

Obviously this has a problem: it's also capturing the comma each time. Any idea how I can leave it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Fede's answer, here's a complete snippet that does exactly what I needed:

```
// The last keyword is invalid - it begins with a number,
// which is not allowed, so it should not considered a separate keyword
var keywords = "__,dgettext:2,dcgettext:2,ngettext:1,2,dpgettext2:2c,3,__,_n,_,2";
keywords.split(/,(?=[a-z_]+\w*)/gi);
```

What it does is that it looks for commas that are followed by a valid keyword and then splits the string based on that into an array, which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with positive lookahead by using a regex like this:

```
,(?=\w+gettext)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ5eJ5/1)**

Comment: This captures the commas... I need to capture the keywords with arguments. Perhaps this is a good starting point though, but I'm not sure how I would move forward from here?

Comment: @ragulka you have to use that regex to split your strings, then you'd get the content you want

Comment: ah, got it! you're right - I never thought of that. I have adjusted your regex to work with even one-character function names

Comment: @ragulka glad to help. Btw, if you consider your question solved you can mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = /(([\w_]+:\w+(,\w+)*)(?=(,[\w_]+:)|(,_+)|($)))|(_+)/g ;
var test = "--keywords=__,dgettext:2,dcgettext:2,nGettext:1,2,dpgettext2:2c,3,N_:1";
var n = test.match(pattern);
alert(n.length);
alert(n);
```

This looks for symbol:hex,(hex).  dcgettext:2,2c is such a pattern.  The regex is for my symbol is [\w_+], so the pattern for the whole is. /[\w_]+:\w+(,\w+)*/ where I am using \w for 'hex'.  I could use [0-9a-f]+ for hex which would be more correct, but harder to read.

Then I further qualify by requiring the group to be followed by either a comma and another group,  or a comma and an underscore group, or the end of line.  I write this like (?=(,[\w_]+:)|(,_+)($)).

Finally, I also accept stand-alone underscore groups as (_+).

I don't know if this handles all forms of xgettext, I only worked with your example text.  Provide more example text if you want a better working regex.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Especially if they're regexen, given how opaque those usually are.

Comment: This regex doesn't seem to work properly. For the `__` keyword, it only captures the first half, ie `_`. Also, it doesn't capture keywords like `_,Q_,N_,`